# Liferay 6.1 EE / Liferay Developer Studio / Tomcat 7 - Port 8080 already in use?

Tags: liferay, tomcat7

Configuring Liferay Developer Studio on a production machine and receiving error that port 8080 is already in use when trying to start Tomcat 7. Can't find anywhere to change the port or know what could already be running on 8080.

How can I figure out whats already running on 8080 and turn it off?
or 
How can I configure Tomcat to run on another port?

Any help at all is very appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure tomcat's ports in conf/server.xml (search for "port" in there - there are multiple occurrences). Change as you like.

As you talk about a production system: Ideally these should be really administered down, I'd be slightly worried if there's software running that you don't know to be there. You can just connect your browser to http://your.machine:8080/ and check what you see there, assuming that it's answering in the http protocol.

What other tools would be available to detect what's occupying that port is dependent on your operating system. Start with "netstat" ("netstat help" on windows, "man netstat" or "netstat --help" on unix-based OS) - it's available on Windows and Linux, I assume on MacOS as well (can't test). And, of course, in the case of http on a port: Just point your browser to it in order to see what's answering

Comment: I am working off of a mac. But I think I figured out whats wrong, previously I had downloaded an earlier CE edition of Liferay and executed ./startup.sh in another Tomcat (did not realize my organization had set us up on EE). So how do I turn that one off? I just started working with local instances, so I've never been through this process. Thank you.

Comment: A tomcat that you started with startup.sh can be stopped with shutdown.sh from the same folder (provided you didn't change the ports in server.xml in the meantime). Also, after a reboot it will be gone: Starting through startup.sh will only be once, not on every system boot.

Comment: @OlafKock can you suggest some tools to detect the use of ports for OS - Windows7 and MAC OS X Lion? Thanks